# Functional method for storing a query string as a simple key-value object

Tags: javascript, parsing, functional-programming, url

I'm working on an isomorphic javascript module ([query-hash](https://github.com/bcruddy/query-hash)) to handle query strings and base64 tokens. It's essentially a simple key-value object with methods for taking in data and giving it back in the format you ask for.

```
function queryToObject(queryString) {
    return queryString.split('&')
        .map(kv => kv.split('='))
        .reduce((p, kv) => {
            p[kv[0]] = decodeURIComponent(kv[1] || '').replace(/\+/g, ' ');

            return p;
        }, {});
}
```

For the "functional approach", mapping the array created by `split()` seems like unnecessary function calls. Should I be splitting the string in the `reduce()` method? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2):

For this simple use case, you are correct that you could do all this work in a reduce step saving yourself an additional iteration over the array created by the `split()` operation.   Now whether this is enough of a performance impact for your expected use cases to move away from the (probably clearer-to-understand) map-reduce pattern is something that perhaps you would need do some testing to decide how you want to approach the problem.

If for example, you ever foresee yourself adding a `filter()` step, then perhaps keeping separation between map - filter - reduce steps makes sense.

I do think there are some edge cases around your basic query-split approach which might not be handled well here.  For example, what about parameters with array notation (i.e. `param[]=foobar`)?  You can certialny do plenty of search on the internet to gets lots of ideas on how to approach the basic query string parsing logic.

Comment: Good review. It should be noted that the `param[]`-style array notation is an informal convention - but very common one! So handling it isn't a _requirement_ for proper query string parsing, though it may be desirable.

Answer (score 2):

Code seems fine to me, honestly. Keeping the `map` step separate is just as good as incorporating it into `reduce`, since nothing really requires it to be one way or the other.

I would be a bit more explicit in naming, though (e.g. `params` instead of just `p`).

Also, you can use array destructuring to clean up the code a little:

```
function queryToObject(queryString) {
  return queryString
    .split('&')
    .map(pair => pair.split('='))
    .reduce((params, [key, value]) => { // destructure key-value pair
        params[key] = decodeURIComponent(value || '').replace(/\+/g, ' ');
        return params;
    }, {});
}
```

Or, if you incorporate the 2nd split into the `reduce`:

```
function queryToObject(queryString) {
  return queryString
    .split('&')
    .reduce((params, pair) => {
        var [key, value] = pair.split('=');
        params[key] = decodeURIComponent(value || '').replace(/\+/g, ' ');
        return params;
    }, {});
}
```

A completely different approach might be:

```
function queryToObject(queryString) {
  var params = {};
  queryString.replace(/([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/g, function (_, key, value) {
    params[key] = decodeURIComponent(value || '').replace(/\+/g, ' ');
  });
  return params;
}
```